# openpyxl font conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, fonts, conditional-formatting, openpyxl

I am using pyopenxl to output some excel spreadsheets, I encountered a problem with font conditional formatting. I want to highlight the cells lesser than 0 with red color and here's what I've done:

```
from pyopenxl import formatting, styles

red_font = styles.Font(size=self.font_size, bold=bold, color=self.red_color_font)
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=self.red_color, end_color=self.red_color, fill_type='solid')

self.ws.conditional_formatting.add(
    cell.coordinate,
    formatting.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill, font=red_font)
)
```

So I simply created styles for font and fill and applied them for my cell. The bad thing is that it doesn't work. As soon as I remove the font formatting from the `CellIsRule()` everything goes back to normal and I'm having my cell filled with red. But the thing is that I need to change the color as well, does anyone has any idea what's wrong with my code? Or maybe with openpyxl?

Comment: How is `red_color` and `red_color_font` defined? Having red text with a red background would result in a red cell with no visible text.

Comment: They are RGB format strings, like `self.red_color = 'ffc7ce'` and `self.red_color_font = '9c0103'`. I should also add that they work perfectly well in any other situation, just not with conditional formatting :/

Comment: What version of `openpyxl` are you using? `import openpyxl; print openpyxl.__version__`   This seems to work fine for me on `2.2.6`

Comment: I was using `2.2.5` and today switched to `2.2.6` but with no success. Could you please paste your code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To highlight cells that are less than zero, you can use the following code when using `openpyxl` version `2.5.1` and above:

```
from openpyxl import formatting, styles, Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

red_color = 'ffc7ce'
red_color_font = '9c0103'

red_font = styles.Font(size=14, bold=True, color=red_color_font)
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=red_color, end_color=red_color, fill_type='solid')

for row in range(1,10):            
    ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=row-5)
    ws.cell(row=row, column=2, value=row-5)

ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A10', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill, font=red_font))
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B1:B10', formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill))
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

---

For `openpyxl` version `2.2.6` you need to use the following:

```
from openpyxl import formatting, styles

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

red_color = 'ffc7ce'
red_color_font = '9c0103'

red_font = styles.Font(size=14, bold=True, color=red_color_font)
red_fill = styles.PatternFill(start_color=red_color, end_color=red_color, fill_type='solid')

for row in range(1,10):            
    ws.cell(row=row, column=1, value=row-5)
    ws.cell(row=row, column=2, value=row-5)
               
ws.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A10', formatting.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill, font=red_font))
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B1:B10', formatting.CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['0'], fill=red_fill))
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

This displays as follows:

[image]

Comment: Well, if this works for you I guess it's my MacOSX Numbers limitations and its not completely full compatibility with Microsoft Excel. Thanks for clearing this out!

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044582/openpyxl-unexpected-fail-with-cellisrule-function

Comment: In `openpyxl 3.0.5`, `CellIsRule` has moved to: `openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule`