# Openpyxl: unexpected fail with CellIsRule function

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I am opening an Excel file and applying some conditional formatting:

```
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\myfolder')

wb= load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

#Conditional formatting
ws.conditional_formatting.add('S3:S89', formatting.CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['1'], font='#FF0000')) #Red
```

This was done based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451567/openpyxl-font-conditional-formatting?answertab=votes#tab-top). However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-fb94e6065444> in <module>()
---> 10 ws.conditional_formatting.add('S3:S89', formatting.CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['1'], font='#FF0000')) #Red

AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.formatting' has no attribute 'CellIsRule'
```

What's going on? I am using `openpyxl` version 2.4.8, whilst this answer was offered for version 2.2.6. However, the `CellIsRule` function seems to be still present. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following type of approach:

```
import openpyxl

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\myfolder')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

#Conditional formatting
red_font = openpyxl.styles.Font(size=14, bold=True, color='9c0103')
ws.conditional_formatting.add('S3:S89', openpyxl.formatting.rule.CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['1'], font=red_font)) #Red
```

Comment: You would need to remove `formatting.` before `CellIsRule()` and then you need to specify an actual font.